# Get the seed for a specific dataset

Tags: c#, random

I recently played with the `Random` class and it came to my mind to "reverse" the seed process.
For example: The seed `10000` produces this dataset: `0x32 0xb3 0x84 0xf5 0x30`.

```
Random random = new Random(10000);
byte[] storage = new byte[5];

random.NextBytes(storage);
```

**My question** is, if it is possible to get the seed for a given dataset.
Something like: `var seed = GetSeed(new byte[] { 0x32, 0xb3, 0x84, 0xf5, 0x30 }); // returns 10000`

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible (somehow like it isn't possible to revert a hash to it's source text) but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If you want to reverse engineer the process, here is the Random.cs source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs

Comment: Look at this constructor and you'll notice that it can't be reversed: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,92e3cf6e56571d5a,references

Comment: You have to try every possible seed.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with a caveat (see below) without even peeking into the implementation, just by trying all possible seeds. There's a finite number of them, so this is definitely computable. Actually it won't even take very long, there are only about 2 billion (negative seeds get negated) seeds.

The caveat is that multiple *actually different* seeds (so ignoring the negative seeds) can generate a sequence that starts the same. For the obvious case, think about 1-byte sequences - there are many more seeds than 256, so they have to get reused. Longer sequences could just get unlucky.

> somehow like it isn't possible to revert a hash to it's source text

You can generate a pre-image of a hash in the same way, just try everything (all strings, starting with short ones - while there are infinitely many strings, you will find a match in finite time if reasonable assumptions about the hash function hold). The difference is that hashes are bigger, so it takes too long. Of course multiple strings map to the same hash so that doesn't mean you will find the original text, but you can, in theory, find a text that is "just as good" as the original text.